# why my function don't return the last value?

Tags: python, class, oop, if-statement

I have written class called `Atoms` and I put inside it, in short, all the information you need in order to work on distributing the electrons of some atoms, and I put it in a dictionary `dict`, `its symbol is the key and its atomic number is the value`, and I made a set of conditional sentences in order to distribute the atoms and put them inside a `list`, but it excludes the last value and Don't put it on the list.

This is my code:

```
class Atoms:
    
    def __init__(self, protons, neutrons, electrons):
        self.protons = protons
        self.neutrons = neutrons 
        self.electrons = electrons

    def atoms_info(the_atom_name):
        global Atoms_info
        global Atomic_Number
        Atoms_info = {"H": ("Hydrogen", "Atomic Number : 1"), "He": ("Helium", "Atomic Number : 2"), "Li": ("Lithium", "Atomic Number : 3"),"Be": ("Beryllium", "Atomic Number : 4"),
        "B": ("Boron", "Atomic Number : 5"),"C": ("Carbon", "Atomic Number : 6"), "N": ("Nitrogen", "Atomic Number : 7"),"O": ("Oxygen", "Atomic Number : 8"),
        "F": ("Fluorine", "Atomic Number : 9"), "Ne": ("Neon", "Atomic Number : 10"), "Na": ("Sodium", "Atomic Number : 11"), "Mg": ("Magnesium", "Atomic Number : 12"),
        "Al": ("Aluminium", "Atomic Number : 13"), "Si": ("Silicon", "Atomic Number : 14"), "P": ("Phosphorus", "Atomic Number : 15"), "S": ("Sulfur", "Atomic Number : 16"),
        "Cl": ("Chlorine", "Atomic Number : 17"), "Ar": ("Argon", "Atomic Number : 18"), "K": ("Potassium", "Atomic Number : 19"), "Ca": ("Calcium", "Atomic Number : 20"),
        "Sc": ("Scandium", "Atomic Number : 21"), "Ti": ("Titanium", "Atomic Number : 22"), "V": ("Vanadium", "Atomic Number : 23"), "Cr": ("Chromium", "Atomic Number : 24"),
        "Mn": ("Manganese", "Atomic Number : 25"), "Fe": ("Iron", "Atomic Number : 26"), "Co": ("Cobalt", "Atomic Number : 27"), "Ni": ("Nickel", "Atomic Number : 28"),
        "Cu": ("Copper", "Atomic Number : 29"), "Zn": ("Zinc", "Atomic Number : 30"), "Ga": ("Gallium", "Atomic Number : 31"), "Ge": ("Germanium", "Atomic Number : 32"),
        "As": ("Arsenic", "Atomic Number : 33"), "Se": ("Selenium", "Atomic Number : 34"), "Br": ("Bromine", "Atomic Number : 35"), "Kr": ("Krypton", "Atomic Number : 36"),
        "Rb": ("Rubidium", "Atomic Number : 37"), "Sr": ("Strontium", "Atomic Number : 38"), "Y": ("Yttrium", "Atomic Number : 39"), "Zr": ("Zirconium", "Atomic Number : 40"),
        "Nb": ("Niobium", "Atomic Number : 41"), "Mo": ("Molybdenum", "Atomic Number : 42"), "Tc": ("Technetium", "Atomic Number : 43"), "Ru": ("Ruthenium", "Atomic Number : 44"),
        "Rh": ("Rhodium", "Atomic Number : 45"), "Pd": ("Palladium", "Atomic Number : 46"), "Ag": ("Silver", "Atomic Number : 47"), "Cd": ("Cadmium", "Atomic Number : 48"),
        "In": ("Indium", "Atomic Number : 49"), "Sn": ("Tin", "Atomic Number : 50"), "Sb": ("Antimony", "Atomic Number : 51"), "Te": ("Tellurium", "Atomic Number : 52"),
        "I": ("Iodine", "Atomic Number : 53"), "Xe": ("Xenon", "Atomic Number : 54"), "Cs": ("Caesium", "Atomic Number : 55"), "Ba": ("Barium", "Atomic Number : 56"),
        "La": ("Lanthanum", "Atomic Number : 57"), "Ce": ("Cerium", "Atomic Number : 58"), "Pr": ("Praseodymium", "Atomic Number : 59"), "Nd": ("Neodymium", "Atomic Number : 60"),
        "Pm": ("Promethium", "Atomic Number : 61"), "Sm": ("Samarium", "Atomic Number : 62"), "Eu": ("Europium", "Atomic Number : 63"), "Gd": ("Gadolinium", "Atomic Number : 64"),
        "Tb": ("Terbium", "Atomic Number : 65"), "Dy": ("Dysprosium", "Atomic Number : 66"), "Ho": ("Holmium", "Atomic Number : 67"), "Er": ("Erbium", "Atomic Number : 68"),
        "Tm": ("Thulium", "Atomic Number : 69"), "Yb": ("Ytterbium", "Atomic Number : 70"), "Lu": ("Lutetium", "Atomic Number : 71"), "Hf": ("Hafnium", "Atomic Number : 72"),
        "Ta": ("Tantalum", "Atomic Number : 73"), "W": ("Tungsten", "Atomic Number : 74"), "Re": ("Rhenium", "Atomic Number : 75"), "Os": ("Osmium", "Atomic Number : 76"),
        "Ir": ("Iridium", "Atomic Number : 77"), "Pt": ("Platinum", "Atomic Number : 78"), "Au": ("Gold", "Atomic Number : 79"), "Hg": ("Mercury", "Atomic Number : 80"),
        "Tl": ("Thallium", "Atomic Number : 81"), "Pb": ("Lead", "Atomic Number : 82"), "Bi": ("Bismuth", "Atomic Number : 83"), "Po": ("Polonium", "Atomic Number : 84"),
        "At": ("Astatine", "Atomic Number : 85"), "Rn": ("Radon", "Atomic Number : 86"), "Fr": ("Francium", "Atomic Number : 87"), "Ra": ("Radium", "Atomic Number : 88"),
        "Ac": ("Actinium", "Atomic Number : 89"), "Th": ("Thorium", "Atomic Number : 90"), "Pa": ("Protactinium", "Atomic Number : 91"), "U": ("Uranium", "Atomic Number : 92"),
        "Np": ("Neptunium", "Atomic Number : 93"), "Pu": ("Plutonium", "Atomic Number : 94"), "Am": ("Americium", "Atomic Number : 95"), "Cm": ("Curium", "Atomic Number : 96"),
        "Bk": ("Berkelium", "Atomic Number : 97"), "Cf": ("Californium", "Atomic Number : 98"), "Es": ("Einsteinium", "Atomic Number : 99"), "Fm": ("Fermium", "Atomic Number : 100"),
        "Md": ("Mendelevium", "Atomic Number : bitcoin101"), "No": ("Nobelium", "Atomic Number : 102"), "Lr": ("Lawrencium", "Atomic Number : 103"), "Rf": ("Rutherfordium", "Atomic Number : 104"),
        "Db": ("Dubnium", "Atomic Number : 105"), "Sg": ("Seaborgium", "Atomic Number : 106"), "Bh": ("Bohrium", "Atomic Number : 107"), "Hs": ("Hassium", "Atomic Number : 108"),
        "Mt": ("Meitnerium", "Atomic Number : 109"), "Ds": ("Darmstadtium", "Atomic Number : 110"), "Rg": ("Roentgenium", "Atomic Number : 111"), "Cn": ("Copernicium", "Atomic Number : 112"),
        "Nh": ("Nihonium", "Atomic Number : 113"), "Fl": ("Flerovium", "Atomic Number : 114"), "Mc": ("Moscovium", "Atomic Number : 115"), "Lv": ("Livermorium", "Atomic Number : 116"),
        "Ts": ("Tennessine", "Atomic Number : 117"), "Og": ("Oganesson", "Atomic Number : 118")}
        if the_atom_name == 'all_info':
            for key, value in Atoms_info.items():
                print(key, value)

        elif the_atom_name == 'symbol':
            temp = 1
            for key in Atoms_info:
                print(f'Key_{temp} : {key}')
                temp += 1
        else:
            print(Atoms_info.get(the_atom_name, 'No atom has this symbol'))

        Atomic_Number = {"H": 1, "He": 2, "Li": 3, "Be": 4, "B": 5, "C": 6, "N": 7, "O": 8, "F": 9, "Ne": 10,
        "Na": 11, "Mg": 12, "Al": 13, "Si": 14, "P": 15, "S": 16, "Cl": 17, "Ar": 18, "K": 19, "Ca": 20,"Sc": 21, "Ti": 22,
        "V": 23, "Cr": 24, "Mn": 25, "Fe": 26, "Co": 27, "Ni": 28, "Cu": 29, "Zn": 30, "Ga": 31, "Ge": 32, "As": 33, "Se": 34,
        "Br": 35, "Kr": 36, "Rb": 37, "Sr": 38,"Y": 39, "Zr": 40, "Nb": 41, "Mo": 42, "Tc": 43, "Ru": 44, "Rh": 45, "Pd": 46,
        "Ag": 47,"Cd": 48, "In": 49, "Sn": 50, "Sb": 51, "Te": 52, "I": 53, "Xe": 54, "Cs": 55, "Ba": 56, "La": 57, "Ce": 58,
        "Pr": 59,"Nd": 60, "Pm": 61, "Sm": 62, "Eu": 63, "Gd": 64, "Tb": 65, "Dy": 66, "Ho": 67, "Er": 68, "Tm": 69, "Yb": 70,
        "Lu": 71, "Hf": 72, "Ta": 73, "W": 74, "Re": 75, "Os": 76,"Ir": 77, "Pt": 78, "Au": 79, "Hg": 80, "Tl": 81, "Pb": 82,
        "Bi": 83, "Po": 84, "At": 85, "Rn": 86, "Fr": 87, "Ra": 88, "Ac": 89, "Th": 90, "Pa": 91, "U": 92, "Np": 93, "Pu": 94,
        "Am": 95, "Cm": 96, "Bk": 97, "Cf": 98, "Es": 99, "Fm": 100, "Md": 101, "No": 102, "Lr": 103, "Rf": 104, "Db": 105,
        "Sg": 106, "Bh": 107, "Hs": 108, "Mt": 109, "Ds": 110, "Rg": 111, "Cn": 112, "Nh": 113, "Fl": 114, "Mc": 115, "Lv": 116,
        "Ts": 117, "Og": 118}
        
    @classmethod 
    def e_orbit(self, element):
        self.element = element
        Atomic_Number = {"H": 1, "He": 2, "Li": 3, "Be": 4, "B": 5, "C": 6, "N": 7, "O": 8, "F": 9, "Ne": 10,
        "Na": 11, "Mg": 12, "Al": 13, "Si": 14, "P": 15, "S": 16, "Cl": 17, "Ar": 18, "K": 19, "Ca": 20,"Sc": 21, "Ti": 22,
        "V": 23, "Cr": 24, "Mn": 25, "Fe": 26, "Co": 27, "Ni": 28, "Cu": 29, "Zn": 30, "Ga": 31, "Ge": 32, "As": 33, "Se": 34,
        "Br": 35, "Kr": 36, "Rb": 37, "Sr": 38,"Y": 39, "Zr": 40, "Nb": 41, "Mo": 42, "Tc": 43, "Ru": 44, "Rh": 45, "Pd": 46,
        "Ag": 47,"Cd": 48, "In": 49, "Sn": 50, "Sb": 51, "Te": 52, "I": 53, "Xe": 54, "Cs": 55, "Ba": 56, "La": 57, "Ce": 58,
        "Pr": 59,"Nd": 60, "Pm": 61, "Sm": 62, "Eu": 63, "Gd": 64, "Tb": 65, "Dy": 66, "Ho": 67, "Er": 68, "Tm": 69, "Yb": 70,
        "Lu": 71, "Hf": 72, "Ta": 73, "W": 74, "Re": 75, "Os": 76,"Ir": 77, "Pt": 78, "Au": 79, "Hg": 80, "Tl": 81, "Pb": 82,
        "Bi": 83, "Po": 84, "At": 85, "Rn": 86, "Fr": 87, "Ra": 88, "Ac": 89, "Th": 90, "Pa": 91, "U": 92, "Np": 93, "Pu": 94,
        "Am": 95, "Cm": 96, "Bk": 97, "Cf": 98, "Es": 99, "Fm": 100, "Md": 101, "No": 102, "Lr": 103, "Rf": 104, "Db": 105,
        "Sg": 106, "Bh": 107, "Hs": 108, "Mt": 109, "Ds": 110, "Rg": 111, "Cn": 112, "Nh": 113, "Fl": 114, "Mc": 115, "Lv": 116,
        "Ts": 117, "Og": 118}
#                                          the problem

        e_dist = []
        Atomic_number_tmp = Atomic_Number[element]
        while Atomic_number_tmp != 0:

            if Atomic_number_tmp == 1:
                e_dist.append(1)
                break

            else:
                e_dist.append(2)
                Atomic_number_tmp - 2

                if Atomic_number_tmp <= 0:
                    break

                else:
                    if (Atomic_number_tmp - 8) == 0:
                         e_dist.append(8)
                         break

                    elif (Atomic_number_tmp - 8) > 0:
                        e_dist.append(8)
                        Atomic_number_tmp - 8

                        if Atomic_number_tmp <= 0:
                            break

                        elif Atomic_number_tmp > 0 and Atomic_number_tmp <= 7:
                            e_dist.append(Atomic_number_tmp)

                    elif (Atomic_number_tmp - 8) < 0:
                        break
                break
        print(e_dist)


# TEST FUNCTION
Atoms.e_orbit("Na")
```

The it's return `[2, 8]`, **But it must return [2, 8, 1]**

I tried to read the code to understand the exact problem, but it is very complicated, **I hope anybody can help my to solve this problem and make my code more readable**.

*Thank you for reading*.

Comment: Please note that classmethod decorater conflicts with self.

Comment: `@classmethod; def e_orbit(self, element)` notice that `self` points not to an instance but to a class, hence `element` is a class attribute!

Comment: such statements `Atomic_number_tmp - 2` have no effects on `Atomic_number_tmp` variable. Maybe `Atomic_number_tmp =- 2`?

Comment: to make your code more readable avoid global variables, and define the huge dictionaries outside the class. I don't know exactly the goal of the class but I would rename it as `Atom` since the attributes uniquely define an _atom_

Comment: @NameVergessen when I delete it I have this ( Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Projects UD\Crackt GUI App\Science.py", line 314, in <module>
    Atoms.e_orbit("Na")
TypeError: Atoms.e_orbit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given)

Comment: @cards when I add it's return [2]

Comment: just delete the classmethod is not enough, you need to format the code as well. The origin of that error is `Atoms.e_orbit()`, you should call the instance `Atoms().e_orbit()`

Comment: it returns `[2]` because that's what `e_orbit` does. You should explain the meaning of the terms of `[2, 8, 1]`

Comment: Are you ever going to make an instance of Atoms - e.g. `something=Atoms(39,50,39)`?? Or is Atoms simple a container for all that information?

Comment: `..it's return [2, 8], But it must return [2, 8, 1]` - Your code doesn't [return](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is my int4erpretation of your code.

1. global statements should be avoided at all cost.
   You can make your attributs class atributes by adding them drictly to the class. It fullfills the same purpuse but it is much clearer and your functions loose code and are easyier to read. Thats just style thouhg. I **NEVER** use `global`.
2. You do not asing your changes. `variable -1`does not change the variable try `variable -= 1`.
3. You assinged your one twice. I assume by mistake.
4. I reduced the code just to get a bit of overview.
5. Statichmethod something similar as classmethod. But i am unsure about that. Please note that in your code the classmethod decorator is not at the right place. One whitespace is missing.

```py
class Atoms:
    ATOMIC_NUMBER = {"H": 1, "He": 2, "Li": 3, "Be": 4, "B": 5, "C": 6, "N": 7, "O": 8, "F": 9, "Ne": 10,
        "Na": 11, "Mg": 12, "Al": 13, "Si": 14, "P": 15, "S": 16, "Cl": 17, "Ar": 18, "K": 19, "Ca": 20,"Sc": 21, "Ti": 22,
        "V": 23, "Cr": 24, "Mn": 25, "Fe": 26, "Co": 27, "Ni": 28, "Cu": 29, "Zn": 30, "Ga": 31, "Ge": 32, "As": 33, "Se": 34,
        "Br": 35, "Kr": 36, "Rb": 37, "Sr": 38,"Y": 39, "Zr": 40, "Nb": 41, "Mo": 42, "Tc": 43, "Ru": 44, "Rh": 45, "Pd": 46,
        "Ag": 47,"Cd": 48, "In": 49, "Sn": 50, "Sb": 51, "Te": 52, "I": 53, "Xe": 54, "Cs": 55, "Ba": 56, "La": 57, "Ce": 58,
        "Pr": 59,"Nd": 60, "Pm": 61, "Sm": 62, "Eu": 63, "Gd": 64, "Tb": 65, "Dy": 66, "Ho": 67, "Er": 68, "Tm": 69, "Yb": 70,
        "Lu": 71, "Hf": 72, "Ta": 73, "W": 74, "Re": 75, "Os": 76,"Ir": 77, "Pt": 78, "Au": 79, "Hg": 80, "Tl": 81, "Pb": 82,
        "Bi": 83, "Po": 84, "At": 85, "Rn": 86, "Fr": 87, "Ra": 88, "Ac": 89, "Th": 90, "Pa": 91, "U": 92, "Np": 93, "Pu": 94,
        "Am": 95, "Cm": 96, "Bk": 97, "Cf": 98, "Es": 99, "Fm": 100, "Md": 101, "No": 102, "Lr": 103, "Rf": 104, "Db": 105,
        "Sg": 106, "Bh": 107, "Hs": 108, "Mt": 109, "Ds": 110, "Rg": 111, "Cn": 112, "Nh": 113, "Fl": 114, "Mc": 115, "Lv": 116,
        "Ts": 117, "Og": 118}
    
    ATOM_INFO = {"H": ("Hydrogen", "Atomic Number : 1"), "He": ("Helium", "Atomic Number : 2"), "Li": ("Lithium", "Atomic Number : 3"),"Be": ("Beryllium", "Atomic Number : 4"),
        "B": ("Boron", "Atomic Number : 5"),"C": ("Carbon", "Atomic Number : 6"), "N": ("Nitrogen", "Atomic Number : 7"),"O": ("Oxygen", "Atomic Number : 8"),
        "F": ("Fluorine", "Atomic Number : 9"), "Ne": ("Neon", "Atomic Number : 10"), "Na": ("Sodium", "Atomic Number : 11"), "Mg": ("Magnesium", "Atomic Number : 12"),
        "Al": ("Aluminium", "Atomic Number : 13"), "Si": ("Silicon", "Atomic Number : 14"), "P": ("Phosphorus", "Atomic Number : 15"), "S": ("Sulfur", "Atomic Number : 16"),
        "Cl": ("Chlorine", "Atomic Number : 17"), "Ar": ("Argon", "Atomic Number : 18"), "K": ("Potassium", "Atomic Number : 19"), "Ca": ("Calcium", "Atomic Number : 20"),
        "Sc": ("Scandium", "Atomic Number : 21"), "Ti": ("Titanium", "Atomic Number : 22"), "V": ("Vanadium", "Atomic Number : 23"), "Cr": ("Chromium", "Atomic Number : 24"),
        "Mn": ("Manganese", "Atomic Number : 25"), "Fe": ("Iron", "Atomic Number : 26"), "Co": ("Cobalt", "Atomic Number : 27"), "Ni": ("Nickel", "Atomic Number : 28"),
        "Cu": ("Copper", "Atomic Number : 29"), "Zn": ("Zinc", "Atomic Number : 30"), "Ga": ("Gallium", "Atomic Number : 31"), "Ge": ("Germanium", "Atomic Number : 32"),
        "As": ("Arsenic", "Atomic Number : 33"), "Se": ("Selenium", "Atomic Number : 34"), "Br": ("Bromine", "Atomic Number : 35"), "Kr": ("Krypton", "Atomic Number : 36"),
        "Rb": ("Rubidium", "Atomic Number : 37"), "Sr": ("Strontium", "Atomic Number : 38"), "Y": ("Yttrium", "Atomic Number : 39"), "Zr": ("Zirconium", "Atomic Number : 40"),
        "Nb": ("Niobium", "Atomic Number : 41"), "Mo": ("Molybdenum", "Atomic Number : 42"), "Tc": ("Technetium", "Atomic Number : 43"), "Ru": ("Ruthenium", "Atomic Number : 44"),
        "Rh": ("Rhodium", "Atomic Number : 45"), "Pd": ("Palladium", "Atomic Number : 46"), "Ag": ("Silver", "Atomic Number : 47"), "Cd": ("Cadmium", "Atomic Number : 48"),
        "In": ("Indium", "Atomic Number : 49"), "Sn": ("Tin", "Atomic Number : 50"), "Sb": ("Antimony", "Atomic Number : 51"), "Te": ("Tellurium", "Atomic Number : 52"),
        "I": ("Iodine", "Atomic Number : 53"), "Xe": ("Xenon", "Atomic Number : 54"), "Cs": ("Caesium", "Atomic Number : 55"), "Ba": ("Barium", "Atomic Number : 56"),
        "La": ("Lanthanum", "Atomic Number : 57"), "Ce": ("Cerium", "Atomic Number : 58"), "Pr": ("Praseodymium", "Atomic Number : 59"), "Nd": ("Neodymium", "Atomic Number : 60"),
        "Pm": ("Promethium", "Atomic Number : 61"), "Sm": ("Samarium", "Atomic Number : 62"), "Eu": ("Europium", "Atomic Number : 63"), "Gd": ("Gadolinium", "Atomic Number : 64"),
        "Tb": ("Terbium", "Atomic Number : 65"), "Dy": ("Dysprosium", "Atomic Number : 66"), "Ho": ("Holmium", "Atomic Number : 67"), "Er": ("Erbium", "Atomic Number : 68"),
        "Tm": ("Thulium", "Atomic Number : 69"), "Yb": ("Ytterbium", "Atomic Number : 70"), "Lu": ("Lutetium", "Atomic Number : 71"), "Hf": ("Hafnium", "Atomic Number : 72"),
        "Ta": ("Tantalum", "Atomic Number : 73"), "W": ("Tungsten", "Atomic Number : 74"), "Re": ("Rhenium", "Atomic Number : 75"), "Os": ("Osmium", "Atomic Number : 76"),
        "Ir": ("Iridium", "Atomic Number : 77"), "Pt": ("Platinum", "Atomic Number : 78"), "Au": ("Gold", "Atomic Number : 79"), "Hg": ("Mercury", "Atomic Number : 80"),
        "Tl": ("Thallium", "Atomic Number : 81"), "Pb": ("Lead", "Atomic Number : 82"), "Bi": ("Bismuth", "Atomic Number : 83"), "Po": ("Polonium", "Atomic Number : 84"),
        "At": ("Astatine", "Atomic Number : 85"), "Rn": ("Radon", "Atomic Number : 86"), "Fr": ("Francium", "Atomic Number : 87"), "Ra": ("Radium", "Atomic Number : 88"),
        "Ac": ("Actinium", "Atomic Number : 89"), "Th": ("Thorium", "Atomic Number : 90"), "Pa": ("Protactinium", "Atomic Number : 91"), "U": ("Uranium", "Atomic Number : 92"),
        "Np": ("Neptunium", "Atomic Number : 93"), "Pu": ("Plutonium", "Atomic Number : 94"), "Am": ("Americium", "Atomic Number : 95"), "Cm": ("Curium", "Atomic Number : 96"),
        "Bk": ("Berkelium", "Atomic Number : 97"), "Cf": ("Californium", "Atomic Number : 98"), "Es": ("Einsteinium", "Atomic Number : 99"), "Fm": ("Fermium", "Atomic Number : 100"),
        "Md": ("Mendelevium", "Atomic Number : bitcoin101"), "No": ("Nobelium", "Atomic Number : 102"), "Lr": ("Lawrencium", "Atomic Number : 103"), "Rf": ("Rutherfordium", "Atomic Number : 104"),
        "Db": ("Dubnium", "Atomic Number : 105"), "Sg": ("Seaborgium", "Atomic Number : 106"), "Bh": ("Bohrium", "Atomic Number : 107"), "Hs": ("Hassium", "Atomic Number : 108"),
        "Mt": ("Meitnerium", "Atomic Number : 109"), "Ds": ("Darmstadtium", "Atomic Number : 110"), "Rg": ("Roentgenium", "Atomic Number : 111"), "Cn": ("Copernicium", "Atomic Number : 112"),
        "Nh": ("Nihonium", "Atomic Number : 113"), "Fl": ("Flerovium", "Atomic Number : 114"), "Mc": ("Moscovium", "Atomic Number : 115"), "Lv": ("Livermorium", "Atomic Number : 116"),
        "Ts": ("Tennessine", "Atomic Number : 117"), "Og": ("Oganesson", "Atomic Number : 118")}
    
    def __init__(self, protons, neutrons, electrons):
        self.protons = protons
        self.neutrons = neutrons
        self.electrons = electrons

    def atoms_info(the_atom_name):
        
        if the_atom_name == 'all_info':
            for key, value in Atoms.ATOM_INFO.items():
                print(key, value)

        elif the_atom_name == 'symbol':
            temp = 1
            for key in Atoms.ATOM_INFO:
                print(f'Key_{temp} : {key}')
                temp += 1
        else:
            print(Atoms.ATOM_INFO.get(the_atom_name, 'No atom has this symbol'))
    
    @staticmethod
    def e_orbit(element):
        element = element
        
        
        # the problem
        e_dist = []
        Atomic_number_tmp = Atoms.ATOMIC_NUMBER[element]
        while Atomic_number_tmp > 0:

            if Atomic_number_tmp == 1:
                Atomic_number_tmp -= 1
                e_dist.append(1)
                break

            else:
                e_dist.append(2)
                Atomic_number_tmp -= 2
                
                if Atomic_number_tmp > 0:
                    if (Atomic_number_tmp - 8) == 0:
                         e_dist.append(8)

                    elif (Atomic_number_tmp - 8) > 0:
                        e_dist.append(8)
                        Atomic_number_tmp -= 8

                        if Atomic_number_tmp > 1 and Atomic_number_tmp <= 8:
                            # second append for one was here i am nit clear if that was correct
                            e_dist.append(Atomic_number_tmp)

                    elif (Atomic_number_tmp - 8) < 0:
                        continue

# TEST FUNCTION
Atoms.e_orbit("Na")
```

Comment: maybe `atoms_info` as class method so you don't need to call always `Atoms.smt`

Comment: I never used `classmethod`. So I am unsure about the difference.

Comment: with a class method you may have also access to class attributes such as `Atoms.ATOMIC_NUMBER`. `classmethod; def atoms_info(cls, the_atom_name): .... cls.ATOMIC_NUMBER`. Same for `e_orbit`

Comment: Thanks I don't know how I forget that ^_^♥